# Prepared Statement in Java/SQL Server not returning any results

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, maven

```
List<Guest> guestList = new ArrayList<>();
String query = "select * from Guests where ? like ?";
System.out.println("select * from Guests where " + property + " like '%" + value + "%'");
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setString(1, property);
preparedStatement.setString(2, "'%" + value + "%'");
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
guestList = getGuestListFromResultSet(resultSet);
return guestList;
```

As you can see above, I created a Prepared Statement, which is later populated with 2 values: property and value. Running the above query should give me some results in SQL Server.
I also tried these variations for setting the second parameter(value):

```
preparedStatement.setString(2, "%" + value + "%");
preparedStatement.setString(2, value);
```

None of these seem to work. What does work is simply building the query from string concatenation:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from Guests where " + property + " like '" + value + "'");
```

However, I want to use a Prepared Statement.

Comment: You can't pass object names (views, tables, columns, etc.) as preparedStatement parameter values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a variable as a column name. Instead, you can use dynamic SQL

```
String query = """
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
select *
from Guests
where ' + QUOTENAME(?) + ' like @value;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@value nvarchar(100)',
  @value = ?;
""";
```

Note the use of `QUOTENAME` to correctly escape the column name.

Note also the use of `sp_executesql` to pass the value all the way through.

> I'm not sure about the JDBC driver, but ideally you should use proper named parameters, rather than `?`